# How to turn off screen with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, display, powershell, display-settings

I need to be able to turn off my screen instantly manually.

I tried *powercfg /change monitor-timeout-ac 0*, but looks like setting the value to 0 turns it to never. Values like 0.1 also change it to never.

Is there any way I can set this value to 0 minutes, or is there another command that i can use to turn off my screen manually?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [this TechNet scripting page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Turn-off-screen-4d173e0a):

```
powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

Answer (score 6):

**(Running this has the side effect of also locking the workstation in Windows 10. You will need to know the password in order to log back in)**

Running in Powershell:

```
(Add-Type '[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

Would be the correct answer in order to turn off the display. Yes, it also turns off the display on a laptop using Powershell (and some .NET C# code)

Answer (score 2):

Previous solutions work, but they lock powershell input.

Another approach to keep powershell input alive is using `PostMessage` instead of `SendMessage`.

```
(Add-Type "[DllImport(""user32.dll"")] public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);" -Name "Win32PostMessage" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru)::PostMessage(0xffff, 0x0112, 0xF170, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Win10 and working

```
(Add-Type -MemberDefinition "[DllImport(""user32.dll"")]`npublic static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);" -Name "Win32SendMessage" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru)::SendMessage(0xffff, 0x0112, 0xF170, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

DisplayConfig is the thing to use !

For other people that would find this post here you can find the workaround :

Install DisplayConfig module : [PowerShell Gallery | DisplayConfig](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DisplayConfig)

Get your display infos (look at monitor ID) : `Get-DisplayInfo`

You should get something like this :

```
PS C:\Users\user1> Get-DisplayInfo

 DisplayId DisplayName      Active  Primary Position    Mode           ConnectionType  --------- -----------      ------  ------- --------   
----                  --------------
         1 PHL 272V8          True     True 0 0         1920x1080@74,973 Hz      DisplayPort
         2 Mi Monitor         True    False 1920 0      3440x1440@144 Hz         DisplayPort
         3 Philips UHDTV     False    False 0 0                                         HDMI
```

You can get a list of commands by using `Get-Command -Module DisplayConfig`

```
PS C:\Users\user1> Get-Command -Module DisplayConfig

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Copy-DisplaySource                                 1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Disable-Display                                    1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Disable-DisplayAdvancedColor                       1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Enable-Display                                     1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Enable-DisplayAdvancedColor                        1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Get-DisplayColorInfo                               1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Get-DisplayConfig                                  1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Get-DisplayInfo                                    1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Get-DisplayProfile                                 1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Get-DisplayScale                                   1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayPosition                                1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayPrimary                                 1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayProfile                                 1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayRefreshRate                             1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayResolution                              1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayRotation                                1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Set-DisplayScale                                   1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Undo-DisplayConfigChanges                          1.0.5      DisplayConfig
Cmdlet          Use-DisplayConfig                                  1.0.5      DisplayConfig
```

To Disable any screen use command `Disable-Display [ID]`

To Enable any screen use command `Enable-Display [ID]`